# What is `NSInvocation`? When to use it?

Tags: iphone

What is `NSInvocation`? When and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

[NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s a reification of a message send. In other words, it's an object that represents the sending of a message.

Say your class Foo has a method called -[Foo foo], and a method like this:

```
-(void)doSomething {
  NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: [self methodSignatureForSelector: @selector(foo)]];
  [inv setTarget: self];
  [inv invoke];
}
```

Then saying [self foo] is functionally the same thing as saying [self doSomething].

Why would you want to do this? The [CubePuzzle](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/CubePuzzle/index.html) sample app gives one idea. Another might be to schedule a message send to take place in the future, say as triggered by an NSTimer.

Comment: In one sense, they're identical. In other sense, they're worlds apart: instead of sending a message to an object instantly you can choose to delay that invocation by using an NSInvocation and an NSTimer. Or you could have, like in CubePuzzle, the choice of which selector to run separated from the invocation of that selector (to improve readability/extensibility).